Multiple duplicate Excel files getting downloaded everytime in Chrome and Edge for few users
This issue is not actually faced by me, but few of my collegues faced this...and it's a bit weird...
Trying to replicate it in my system...but not able to...
When they are trying to download an Excel file by clicking on a link, the file is being downloaded twice, PDF's are good...one PDF downloaded per click.
Note: All the people who are facing this issue have updated browser to recent versions and so do I,still myself and couple of others with me are not able to reproduce it.
HTML for that link,
<a href="some_working-url.xlsx" class="class-name" download> Excel_Name </a>
Only one file should be downloaded if we click on this link, but 2 duplicate files are being downloaded.
I tried copying the href url and pasting it in another tab (in their system), then... only one file gets downloaded.
I really think this is something related to browser, but not getting any document or anything solid to confirm that.
Any help here will be much appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Unfortunately, I also failed to replicate this issue, but I would suggest the impacted users turn off Ask when a site tries to download files automatically after the first file (recommended) at edge://settings/content/automaticDownloads.
Once this setting is turned off, multiple automatic downloads can't be performed on any webpage. Of course, if you prefer to only apply it for specific sites, just leave the setting ON and add them into the block list.
For Chrome, you can find same settings at chrome://settings/content/automaticDownloads, but with different names.

Hi @Kendrick Li, making the above change did work, this should be good if someone comes up with that issue to us reg the website, but a bit hard to convey to all users.
Thanks for your time!!

@VEERESHSH If you are trying to configure these settings for your colleagues, you may consider contacting your IT to deploy the group policies for these settings, so all users don't need to configure anything themselves. These policies are: AutomaticDownloadsBlockedForUrls or DefaultAutomaticDownloadsSetting.

Hi again @KendrickLi, the issue is being faced by few of our website users(public) all over the world as well, not just the internal users, I added the description to describe that.. issue is being faced by few but not all and also hoping if there is any code related fix I can provide and test it in their system, apologies if it has created any confusions.
Note: Though turning off that recommended setting solved the issue for people who had the problem, that particular setting is turned-on in my local as well, but still I am not facing it.
Something to check...

Hi @VEERESHSH, for public users, yes it is a bit difficult to let them apply settings themselves, but the code-related fix is currently not present. Is it possible to provide the URL for us to replicate the issue?

Sorry!!, It's an url that's generated and will be available only for the particular user that generated it... thank you for all your efforts really appreciate this, as a new member and my first query here, it's nice to see people trying help each other around the globe. Thanks again and hope someone from Chrome or Edge sees this and fix the issue ;-)

@VEERESHSH Yea, that's fine. You may send feedback inside Edge and Chrome to let the Dev Team know about it. This can contribute to the resolution of this issue. Hope it'll get fixed soon.
